# Facing error while changing meta description

Tags: wordpress

I am following code for name description of my entertainment related wordpress site.

```
 <meta name="description" content="<?php if ( is_single() ) { echo $post->post_content; }else{ ?><?php echo "Website home page description";; } ?>" />
```

I am changing code with this

```
 <meta name="description" content="Watch <?php the_title(); ?> Stream <?php the_title(); ?>  />
```

But after changing this code with old one home page description is not showing up.

Comment: `the_title()` is only available from within The Loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing this outside of The Loop, you should use the `$post` object instead:

```
<meta name="description" 
      content="Watch <?php echo $post->post_title; ?> Stream <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>" />
```